# Sentencia group by no funciona con linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, informix

Estoy tratando de hacer un agrupamiento en una consulta sencilla de linq pero me esta generando un error. Estoy usando entity framework core con una base de datos informix.

Al hacerlo con esta forma inicial (primero cargando los registros en una lista y luego agrupandolos) funciona perfectamente :

```
var listaCentros = (from cen in context.CenopeMaes select cen).ToList();
 var listaTipo = (from tc in listaCentros
                  group tc by tc.CenTipo into grupo
                  select new {
                      Tipo = grupo.Key,
                      Total = grupo.Count()
                  });
```

Pero cuando el agrupamiento directamente desde el contexto se genera una excepcion:

```
var listaTipo2 = (from tc in context.CenopeMaes
                             group tc by tc.CenTipo into grupo
                             select new
                             {
                                 Tipo = grupo.Key,
                                 Total = grupo.Count()
                             }).ToList();
```

Lo mas extraño es que se genera el error :

```
ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] The column (tipo) must be in the GROUP BY list.
```

Que puede ocurrir?

Answer (score 1):

Por el mensaje de error que mencionas pareciera ser un problema con la transfrmacion del linq a la consulta sql que ejecuta informix.

Recomendaria definas el `logging` de `EF Core` para poder obtener la query sql que esta generando

[Logging in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx)

[Logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging)

Asi podras tomarla y ejecutarla en la tool de informix que utilices para validar la estructura.

Agregas en el `dbcontext`

```
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});
```

asi lo asignas

```
public class NombreContext : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] {
              new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)
        });


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);

    }

    //resto codigo
}
```

Nota: No descartaria un problema del provider de informix para ef core

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer en el group by te falta agregar el .key
Prueba el siguiente código:

```
group tc by tc.CenTipo,tc.Key into grupo
```

Comment: como sabes que hay una columna `Key`? la Key se genera al agrupar no previamente